# Unable To Use mindsdb Library In Python

Tags: python, importerror, mindsdb

I am currently trying to install and use mindsdb in python, however when i install it with:

```
pip3 install mindsdb
```

Even though it says:

```
Successfully installed mindsdb-1.99.3
```

I receive the following error when importing it:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mindsdb/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mindsdb_native import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mindsdb_native/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import lightwood
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightwood/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torchvision
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from torchvision import models
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .alexnet import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/models/alexnet.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Could somebody explain what the issue is and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are getting this error on `import mindsdb` ?

Comment: @ZoranPandovski yes

Answer (score 0):

I think there are still some issues going on with torch on Python 3.8. Can you try using the python 3.7.x version? I just checked this out and mindsdb==1.99.3 works with python 3.7.x version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pip3 install mindsdb_native
```